# Magento 2.2.5 google-analytics code not show Frontend

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

We have installed Lastest Magento Version 2.2.5 and Also add google analytics id but not show on frontend

Comment: Where did you add the google analytics ID?

Comment: Stores | Configuration 
Sales > Google API

Google Analytics
Enable: Yes
Account Number: The UA Tracking Code

Save Config

But it's not adding the script on the frontend.
Magento 2.2.5

General > Web > Default Cookie Settings
Cookie Restriction Mode: No

So why does it not show?

Answer (score 0):

I went to

Stores | Configuration Sales > Google API Google Analytics Enable: Yes
Account Number: The UA Tracking Code

Clicked Save Config But

Refreshed front end it's not adding the script confirmed with Tag Assistant extension for Google Chrome.

Version: Magento 2.2.5

Also Cookie Restriction mode is set to No
General > Web > Default Cookie Settings Cookie Restriction Mode: No

Okay what fixed it was silly, for me a cache flush.
Might be doable via admin back end but I mostly use the shell for this.

`bin/magento cache:flush`

Also cleared Cloud Flare and mod page speed caches that were in use just in-case.

Comment: Hi Liam - did you find the solution to this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Yes, ```bin/magento cache:flush``` and cleared cloudflare cache as well appeared to have been the fix in my case.